# Wordpress with docker-compose.yml on CentOS

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, centos

This is my first time trying Vultr with CentOS.

I was able to successfully develop a local Wordpress website with a custom theme, now I'm trying to deploy it to a CentOS server on Vultr.  My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.2.2-php7.1-apache
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

How should I configure the images?
Should I create three images for wordpress, mysql, and wp-content & uploads.ini referencing them in the docker-compose? Or can I make just one image of everything?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by using one service per container. So for `wordpress, mysql etc` it better to use multiple services.

But, these services use one image or multiple images, it totally depends on your scenario.

In fact, you can put all things in one own image, and specify different commands in the image for different docker-compose service. E.g.

```
services:
  db:
    image: your_own_solo_image
    command: the command to start db

  wordpress:
    image: your_own_solo_image
    command: the command to start wordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**Disadvantage for using one image:**

- Maybe one container just need small base image, e.g. alpine, another container need ubuntu, but with unify image(say ubuntu), when two containers run, it will all use ubuntu, maybe some more memory waste as ubuntu will consume more resources compared to alpine.
- You may encountered library conflict, e.g. container1(service1) need `lib.so.1`, while container2(service2) may need `lib.so.2`, you may have to handle `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by yourself. If you separate images, no issue here.

**Advantage for using one image:**

- Sometimes you may want to separate service(command) to different containers, but the two commands really very dependent on one own project's same source code, and the environment is all same, then no need to use different images for different containers(different service in compose). One example is django project, you may start wsgi in one service, but may also want to start celery worker in another service but still use the same code of your django project.